# Bootstrap datetimepicker not working properly inside scrollable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm working with [bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and there I have a scrollable div and inside which I have my date time picker. and there when I scroll and tries to select dates the date time picker windows opens above the textbox

For better illustration I have the image here[image]

Wonder where I messed up with it?

This is what I have coded.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            minDate:new Date()
          });
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false
        });
        $("#datetimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });


        $('#radius').bootstrapSlider({
            formatter: function (value) {
                $('#distance').val(value);
                var v = $('#btn-toggle').find('.active').find('input[name="options"]').val();
                console.log('option = ' + v);
                //alert(v);
                radius = $('#radius').val();
                if (v == 'km') {
                    $('#distance').val(radius);
                }
                else {
                    $('#distance').val(radius * 1000);
                }
                return value;
            }
        });

        $('#btn-toggle').click(function () {

            setTimeout(function () {
                var v = $('#btn-toggle').find('.active').find('input[name="options"]').val();

                //alert(v);

                radius = $('#radius').val();
                if (v == 'km') {
                    $('#distance').val(radius);
                }
                else {
                    $('#distance').val(radius * 1000);
                }
            }, 500);
        });

    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="form-group datetimepicker-cover">
      <input type="text" name="start_time" id="datetimepicker" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" data-name="start_time"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group datetimepicker-cover">
      <input type="text" name="end_time" id="datetimepicker1" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" data-name="end_time"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: remove form-group class and add margin to it

Comment: margin how many pixels?

Comment: you have to decide it for yourself . How you need to show it properly.

Comment: I guess thats the hard coded solution I need a responsive one..

Comment: It will get responsive try it first.

Comment: can you make sure, you have included `bootstrap-datetimepicker.css` file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have included `bootstrap-datetimepicker.css`

Comment: hello I have tried the above suggestions but its not working

Comment: anyone who have witnessed this problem can suggest the proper fix for this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this issue by changing the order and need to modify `.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget` class like this

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  top: auto !important;
  bottom:auto !important;
}
```

I guess the problem in my case was that it doesn't have enough space to popup **even after adding the above fix** so when I changed the order the existing problem got fixed by the above fix.

Hope this will help someone. :)